# How do you show SQL executing on an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

How can you show the SQL that is currently executing on an oracle db?

Extra information that would be useful would include user, session id etc.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Most of the info is available in v$session ... and the SQL Text can be grabbed from v$sql or v$sqltext_with_newlines...

Here is a query that I often use that formats In-flight SQL, longest running at top.

```
-- In Flight SQL 
SELECT nvl(ses.username,'ORACLE PROC')||' ('||ses.sid||')' USERNAME,
       SID,   
       MACHINE, 
       REPLACE(SQL.SQL_TEXT,CHR(10),'') STMT, 
      ltrim(to_char(floor(SES.LAST_CALL_ET/3600), '09')) || ':'
       || ltrim(to_char(floor(mod(SES.LAST_CALL_ET, 3600)/60), '09')) || ':'
       || ltrim(to_char(mod(SES.LAST_CALL_ET, 60), '09'))    RUNT 
  FROM V$SESSION SES,   
       V$SQLtext_with_newlines SQL 
 where SES.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
   and SES.USERNAME is not null
   and SES.SQL_ADDRESS    = SQL.ADDRESS 
   and SES.SQL_HASH_VALUE = SQL.HASH_VALUE 
   and Ses.AUDSID <> userenv('SESSIONID') 
 order by runt desc, 1,sql.piece;
```

Comment: what is the meaning of In Flight SQL?

Comment: In-flight = currently running on an oracle database, or in this case currently available in v$session and status='ACTIVE'

Answer (score 11):

Good answer found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503122524/http://www.dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=7400).

Execute the following sql:

```
select x.sid
      ,x.serial#
      ,x.username
      ,x.sql_id
      ,x.sql_child_number
      ,optimizer_mode
      ,hash_value
      ,address
      ,sql_text
from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
      ,v$session x
where  x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
and    x.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
and    x.username       is not null;
```

If the output is unreadable, change the LINESIZE (take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751843/formatting-output-of-queries-in-sqlplus)):

```
SET LINESIZE 20000
```

If the sql above does not work, you might need to log in as sysdba:

```
sqlplus '/as sysdba'
```

Comment: Your link to the Good answer is dead

Comment: @Gerrat I updated the link to a cached archive.