# Trying to find out what a specific running statement is (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to look into what's running on my Oracle instance at the moemnt.  I have a large INSERT statement going that's dumping data into a table, and I can see this is running when I execute the SQL script referenced in this post:

[How do you show sql executing on an oracle database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database)

It's showing my INSERT statement fine, but it's also showing a second statement that looks like a trigger or a stored procedure that's not referenced in the insert statement: `mp_manual_pay`. This is an abbreviation of the table I'm inserting data into.

I can't find this label referenced in a trigger or a stored procedure, so I'm wondering what else this might be?  I've searched `sys.all_objects` and cannot see any reference to this label / name.

Any ideas on where else to search to see what exactly this is?

I expect it's the cause of a rather slow insert, and I would like to temporarily disable this during the bulk insert.

I have also executed the script referenced in this post:

[How to see the actual Oracle SQL statement that is being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899/how-to-see-the-actual-oracle-sql-statement-that-is-being-executed)

And this certainly seems to indicate that something else is going on, but I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: Does the session information for that statement give a clue? Like the originator machine or login?

Comment: Without the outputs, neither we can.

Comment: The session ID is the same as the original INSERT statement.  Two rows are returned.  One is the insert statement that is issued through a sqlplus session, and the second is "mp_manual_pay" which appears to be an abbreviation of the table that is being inserted into "MANUAL_PAYMENTS".  Initially I thought it was a trigger, but I can't find any object in the database by that identifier.